# can't install oracle 11g on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, oracle, database

when i run installer it stuck in 84% and gives me this error

> Error in invoking target 'install' of makefile '/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/ctx/lib/ins_ctx.mk'.

how can i fix this problem
thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close as `unclear` because α) you're clearly not *installing* but *building* it from a source, and β) you didn't even provide errors from the compilation, just the last line stating that there was a problem.

Answer (score 1):

On my Debian Jessie it helped to install:

```
apt-get install zlib1g-dev
```

And push retry in Oracle installer. On ubuntu it might be similar.